# Write HTML form input to .conf file using PHP

Tags: php, html

I know a lot of questions similar to this have been asked before which I have checked out but I am still having trouble writing my HTML form data to a .conf file. I am trying to write a script which will take the data from a submitted HTML form, create a new .conf file and write the data to the file.

HTML:

```
<form action="filewrite.php" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-10 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" method="POST" name="form" style="padding: 10px;">
            <div class="u-form-group u-form-name">
              <label for="name-26a2" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-1">Collector IP Address</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Collector IP address" name="CollectorIP" minlength="7" maxlength="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" input required class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-14 u-white u-input-1" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="u-form-email u-form-group">
              <label for="email-26a2" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-2">Collector Port</label>
              <input type="number" placeholder="Collector Port" name="CollectorPort" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-14 u-white u-input-2" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="u-form-group u-form-select u-form-group-3">
              <label for="select-7512" class="u-custom-font u-heading-font u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-3">Netflow Version</label>
              <div class="u-form-select-wrapper">
                <select id="select-7512" name="NetflowVersion" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-14 u-white u-input-3" required="required">
                  <option value="Netflow Version 10 (IPFIX)">Netflow Version 10 (IPFIX)</option>
                  <option value="Netflow Version 9">Netflow Version 9</option>
                  <option value="Netflow Version 7">Netflow Version 7</option>
                  <option value="Netflow Version 5">Netflow Version 5</option>
                </select>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="12" version="1" class="u-caret"><path fill="currentColor" d="M4 8L0 4h8z"></path></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-align-left u-form-group u-form-submit">
              <a href="#" class="u-btn u-btn-round u-btn-submit u-button-style u-custom-color-2 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-radius-50 u-btn-1">Submit</a>
              <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Save Data" class="u-form-control-hidden">
            </div>
            <div class="u-form-send-message u-form-send-success">Success, Netflow traffic is now being sent to x.x.x.x:xxxx</div>
            <div class="u-form-send-error u-form-send-message">The simulator was unable to process the request, please try again.</div>
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="recaptchaResponse">
            <input type="hidden" name="formServices" value="b7574ca92d30e67a7edd501c5be4f581">
          </form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
 $path = '/usr/local/flowsim/data/phptest.conf';
 if (isset($_POST['CollectorIP']) && isset($_POST['CollectorPort']) && isset($_POST['NetflowVersion'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['CollectorIP'].' - '.$_POST['CollectorPort'].' - '.$_POST['NetflowVersion'];
    fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
?>
```

The reason for this is to build a tool which is only used internally, I realise having a system that allows users to write .conf files to the server is not best practise however the options available on the HTML form are limited.

Any idea where I might be going wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Well, perhaps if you want to write a .conf file you should actually write to such a file? It seems that currently you're writing to a .php file.

Comment: Your code opens a loophole as you allow unsanitized external input to be written to a file on your server! Worse than that, it's a PHP file and can be executed.

Comment: I think whatever project you are doing, allowing an interface to write (or even worse: access) sensitive informations such as .conf file is an antipattern, just like putting configuration in a database read by the code is also an anti pattern. Maybe you can try editing your post and expose your business problem so the community can guide you towards a better programming approach?

Comment: Fixed the PHP code to actually write to a .conf file, I slipped up their. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was not the issue here. NGINX and PHP-FPM were using mismatched sockets. Checked `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and was getting errors like the below:

```
connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
```

Followed the guide here and was able to fix the problem - https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-php-fpm/